# How can I add an array to hash with hmset in redis

Tags: node.js, redis, hashmap

I store some key/value in a hash in redis. for example I have this json

```
{
"title": "CEO",
"originId": "52",
"status": "A"
}
```

My code to store this json is:

```
await redis.hmset(`role-${roleId}`, { title, originId, status })
```

So now I want to add an array of Ids as a mandatory field to this hash. So how can I add this array to this hash?
My array is something like this:

```
 {
  "mandatories": ["119","120"],
 }
```

Comment: do you just need to store it? (you can just store it as a String) or do you also need to manipulate the array (append, remove...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it as another field in the same hash key, but stringify the array.

```
await redis.hset(`role-${roleId}`, 'mandatories', JSON.stringify(mandatories))
```

This way you can still HGETALL the whole *role* object data. But then, you have to manage the array of IDs as a whole.

Or, you can flatten out the array to a list, set, or sorted set. For example, to add as *set*, you can do:

```
await redis.sadd(`role-${roleId}-mandatories`, mandatories)
```

Note we are adding `'-mandatories'` to the key name. Here you are passing the array to the node.js redis *sadd* function. It will add each array item as a member in the set. This allows you to manipulate the set of mandatories directly (SPOP, SREM, SISMEMBER, etc).

Note that as per Redis 4.0.0, `HMSET` is considered deprecated. Use `HSET` instead.